# Node ssh2: TypeError: <Object> is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh2

I have node `v14.17.0` and ssh2 `1.1.0` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2

I have tried to get the connection working with code below but it crashes on `TypeError: NodeSSH is not a constructor`

I have also tried

```
var NodeSSH= require('ssh2');

var c = new NodeSSH();
```

And

```
var NodeSSH= require('ssh2').Client;
```

And

```
const {NodeSSH} = require('ssh2');
const c = new NodeSSH();

c.on('keyboard-interactive', function(name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) {
    console.log('Connection :: keyboard-interactive');
    finish(['pswd']);
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection :: end');
        console.log(callback());
    }).on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).connect({
        host: 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX',
        username: 'usr',
        port: "22",
        tryKeyboard: true,
        debug: console.log
    });
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Use `const { Client } = require("ssh2");`, It'll work.
Check docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like this, the way you are getting the instance is incorrect.

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2'); // it exports Client not NodeSSH

const conn = new Client();

conn.on('keyboard-interactive', function(name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) {
    console.log('Connection :: keyboard-interactive');
    finish(['pswd']);
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.log('Connection :: end');
        console.log(callback());
    }).on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).connect({
        host: 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX',
        username: 'usr',
        port: "22",
        tryKeyboard: true,
        debug: console.log
    });
```

You should check the documentation how to use it though you have already shared it in the question. I suggest you going through it once.

Comment: Ah thanks, I changed it due to using also ```ssh2-sftp-client``` and due to me being totally new to nodejs just changed the name.

Comment: It happens when you are new and thats fine.